# Infinite products of $C^{\infty}$ functions: criterion for being $C^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I've got a question on infinite products $\Pi_{\nu} f_{\nu}$ with $C^{\infty}$ functions $f_{\nu}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I know about normal convergence and that kind of stuff but didn't find any theorem under which conditions $\Pi_{\nu} f_{\nu}$ is also $C^{\infty}$. Does anybody know of such theorems from real analysis?

Comment: You may try to look at $\sum_\nu \log(f_{\nu})$, if this is defined independently of $\nu$. For series there is a theory for this kind of question.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds promising! By 'theory for this kind of question' you mean the usual rule: in order to be differentiable , convergence at one point plus uniform convergence of the series of derivatives on compact sets is needed. Or do you think of something specific?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.